# Inconsistent Neural Network output

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using the NeuralNet package in R to train an artificial neural network and am able to train a model without much problem. However, when I re-run the model with the same number of hidden nodes and then evaluate my results on my test data I get vastly different results. I was reading a forum post and someone suggested that it has to do with random start weights and it was suggested to set a seed. I have been extremely consistent with setting my seed, but I still get very different results. Has anyone had an issue similar to this? If so, what did you do to fix the inconsistency problem. Also, all of my IV's are numeric and I have no missing values.

Here is my code and output:

```
#min-max norm the dt vars
normalize = function(x){
  return((x-min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
}

#make a smaller dt so it is easier to work with
nrows = nrow(dt.norm)
sm.size = 10000
set.seed(7)
sm.index = sample(nrows, sm.size, replace = FALSE)
dt.norm.sm = dt.norm[sm.index,]

#Split into training and testing
nrows = nrow(dt.norm.sm) 
train.size = floor(0.7*nrows)
set.seed(7)
train.idx = sample(nrows, train.size, replace = F)
dt.sm.train = dt.norm.sm[train.idx, ]
dt.sm.test = dt.norm.sm[-train.idx, ]

#train model on the data
ann.form = as.formula(paste('Pure_Prem ~', paste(names(dt.sm.train[-24]), 
collapse = '+'))) #24 is the dv
pure_prem_model = neuralnet(ann.form, data = dt.sm.train, hidden = 3)

#evaluate model performance
model_results = neuralnet::compute(pure_prem_model, dt.sm.test[1:23]) 
#exclude 24 because it is the DV
predicted_pure_prem = model_results$net.result
cor(predicted_pure_prem, dt.sm.test$Pure_Prem)
```

My output is:

```
[1,] 0.007210471996
```

When I re-run the exact same code again, my output is:

```
[1,] 0.4554126927
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You definitely have to set your seed. The area where I saw this before on Kaggle was when some functions that you use after you set the seed call a random seed internally. If the seed changes your results vastly that's a big red flag that your model results are not very consistent.

Comment: My comment above is the general answer and probably, but not certainly, applies to this. To let us verify this case can you please provide a *reproducible* example? Do you have the same problem if you do it with a buitlin dataset?

Comment: Try one more set.seed before your call to neuralnet::neuralnet(). I think this is your problem and it has to do with setting the initial weights. As a side note, you may also want to try utilizing the rep argument in neuralnet::neuralnet() to improve training.

Comment: You were right. Setting the seed on the line prior to the neuralnet model fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from my comment.

Set up the data:

```
data <- mtcars
samplesize <-  0.6 * nrow(data)
set.seed(7)
index <-  sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), size = samplesize)
max <-  apply(data , 2 , max)
min <-  apply(data, 2 , min)
scale_df <-  as.data.frame(scale(data, center = min, scale = max - min))
train <-  scale_df[index , ]
test <-  scale_df[-index , ]
```

Set up the NN

```
set.seed(6)
model_nn <- neuralnet::neuralnet(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, train, hidden = 3)
model_result <- neuralnet::compute(model_nn, test[,c(2,4,6)])
predicted_mpg <- model_result$net.result
cor(predicted_mpg, test$mpg)
```

Output will always be

```
[1,] 0.9310625412
```

If you omit the `set.seed(6)` before `neuralnet::neuralnet()`, then the output of 5 iterations are:

```
[1,] 0.9142345019
[1,] 0.8531440993
[1,] 0.9414393857
[1,] 0.9309926802
[1,] 0.9164132325
```

Just add the extra `set.seed`. Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is happening is that you are running the calls to `set.seed` once, but running the `neuralnet` function multiple times.

A call to `set.seed` will only produce the same result the first time the function is called after setting the seed. For example

```
set.seed(1)
sample(10)
#[1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
```

If you call the same randomized function a second time, you will get a different result (but still a reproducible one!)

```
sample(10)
#[1]  3  2  6 10  5  7  8  4  1  9
```

See for yourself by calling the seed again.

```
set.seed(1)
sample(10)
# [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
sample(10)
# [1]  3  2  6 10  5  7  8  4  1  9
```

This will give you a new result every time you run the function, but the set of potential results will start over when you "restart" the seed again. You can think of it as `r` starting from the same pseudo-random number each time a seed is set, but then when you call a random function, it starts to "use up" that set of random numbers.

So you have a few options 1) you can run your code from the beginning setting the first seed every time, 2) you can set a seed specifically before your call to `neuralnet` as AndS. suggests, or 3) you can extract some starting weights from the first run of the model, i.e.

```
random_start_weights = pure_prem_mode$startweights
```

and use them explicitly in all future runs

```
pure_prem_model = neuralnet(ann.form, data = dt.sm.train, hidden = 3, startweights = random_start_weights)
```